# RestClient not uploading multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I am trying to call external API and send attachments. Following is working example of curl and multiple attachment

> curl -v -u xxxx@domain.in:password -F
>   "helpdesk_ticket[attachments][][resource]=@/tmp/upload_test_1.txt" -F
>   "helpdesk_ticket[attachments][][resource]=@/tmp/upload_test_2.txt" -F
>   "helpdesk_ticket[email]=testemail@domain.in" -F
>   "helpdesk_ticket[priority]=1" -F "helpdesk_ticket[source]=2" -F
>   "helpdesk_ticket[status]=2" -F
>   "helpdesk_ticket[subject]=TestingSubject" -F
>   "helpdesk_ticket[description]=testingcontent" -X POST
>   url

With this curl request i am able to send and upload multiple attachment. But when i am doing same using my Rails Rest client code its not uploading all attachment its uploading only 1 attachment.

> RestClient::Request.execute(url:
>   "url", method:
>   :post, payload: {"helpdesk_ticket"=>{"description"=>"testingcontent",
>   "subject"=>"TEstingsubject",
>   "email"=>"email@domain.in", "priority"=>1, "source"=>2,
>   "status"=>2, "attachments"=>[{"resource"=>
>   File.new('/tmp/upload_test_1.txt')},{"resource"=>
>   File.new('/tmp/upload_test_2.txt')}],
>   "cc_emails"=>[], "multipart"=>true}, user:
>   "email@domain.in", password: "password", timeout:
>   10)

Any suggestion would be appreciated.